# detect ADB from mobile Android

Tags: android, detection, adb

Can we detect from phone that phone is connected to charger or Android Debug Bridge (ADB)?
and can we shutdown adb server using `adb kill-server` command?

Comment: I mean is phone is connected with charger or with USB cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can detect that phone is connected to charger by receiving broadcast intent [`ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED).
2. AFAIK you can't stop ADB server